# How to get all savepoint states list in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, savepoints

I am learning SQL. I am trying to get all savepoint list. So which command is used to get all savepoint list in a database/table?
I have tried SHOW SAVEPOINTS but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

savepoints only exist during a transaction, within that transaction.  As far as I know, there is no way to list them; since you are in the middle of the code that created them, you are supposed to know what they are named already.